# Integrating .jar file into an Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, integration

I am new to creating Android apps, so forgive me if this sounds very naive. I have a .jar file and the associated .java and .class files. What I want to do is create an Android app (I'm using Eclipse) and somehow integrate the .jar file with it. The .jar file acts as a Spellchecker and I want to create a Spellchecker app, so how should I go about doing this? I know I will have to make changes, of course, but is this possible?

Comment: `Right click project -> Add to buildpath...` and point it to the JAR you want to include. Include it, save, compile, report back.

Comment: @Shark: Your technique has been incorrect for over a year. Gabe Sechan has the proper approach: put the JAR in `libs/` and do not modify the build path manually.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please provide an answer,If possible.

Comment: @Baadshah: As I indicated on your answer, and as I have indicated on multiple other comments, Gabe Sechan's answer is the correct one. While adding a JAR manually to your build path will satisfy the compiler at compile time, it will not add the contents of the JAR to the APK file at runtime, resulting in `ClassNotFoundException`s and the like.

Comment: Oh..Not aware for that.**it will not add the contents of the JAR to the APK file at runtime**.just listening this point :) Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's no UI in the jar (that its just algorithms that you want to use as a library) just drop the jar into the /libs folder, make sure that its added to the project in project properties in Eclipse, and you can then reference it in your project like any other set of classes.

If you do have a UI in there, you'll have to remove it and rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Android documentation show the best way to include private libraries into the project: **Put into libs folder**. Android IDE automatically detect the change and make the magic.  [Android: Managing Projects](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

However you can add a Library project.

Answer (score -1):

In eclipse if you want to add external library (jar file) into your project classpath, you need to add it to project's build path - you will find build path options inside project properties.

Edit:
Drop your jar file into libs folder too. Rest stays valid.

Comment: Your technique has been incorrect for over a year. Gabe Sechan has the proper approach: put the JAR in libs/ and do not modify the build path manually.